# Can you accumulate multiple respecs in Diablo II?

Tags: diablo-ii

With the new patch, you can [respec once per difficulty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/can-you-respec-more-than-once-in-diablo-2) (plus additional respecs if you accumulate the boss drops).

To expand on the information presented in that linked question, do you have to use the respecs once per difficulty, or can I save them up and accumulate 3 respecs by the time I'm on Hell difficulty (plus however many I get through the Cube recipe)?

I'm currently restarting with some friends (I haven't played since the last patch), and I want to know if I'll need to use my normal difficulty respec before I move on to Nightmare.

Comment: didn't see the other old one until recently

Comment: @yx the original (which is linked in my question at the top) is "can you respec more than once".  My question is "if I don't respec between the time I earn it in normal, and the time I earn my second in Nightmare, do I lose the respec from Normal?  Or can I 'stockpile' multiple respecs?"

Comment: fair enough, I didn't catch that part

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have one respec per difficulty by completing the Den of Evil quest from Akara in Act 1. These can be used at any time by starting a game in the appropriate difficulty: one in Normal, one in Nightmare and one in Hell.

Additionally, you can also create a Token of Absolution by transmuting the following items in your Horadric Cube:

1. Twisted Essence of Suffering from either Hell Andariel or Hell Duriel.
2. Charged Essence of Hate from Hell Mephisto
3. Burning Essence of Terror from Hell Diablo
4. Festering Essence of Destruction from Hell Baal

Note that these are all not 100% drops, and are in fact rather rare (< 10%), so it may take quite a few runs to get all the items you need for a full transmute.

The Token of Absolution allows a respec exactly the same as through Akara. Simply right click the token to consume it and respec.

Also note, this is only available in Patch 1.13. This is standard now on closed Battle.net play, but if you're playing single player or Open Battle.net and have not updated to 1.13, these respec methods are not available.

Answer (score 4):

You can save them up, the same as the imbue, personalize or socket quest rewards.

To use them later you create a new (eg) normal game and use the waypoint system to get to the appropriate NPC to use the particular quest reward.  You can do this at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can make [respec tokens](http://www.diablowiki.com/Token_of_Absolution_(Diablo_II)) so you'll never run out of respecs.  It does take a little work to do though, as they drop fairly infrequently.