# Is it possible to re-spec a character that has already completed all quests?

Tags: diablo-ii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you reassign or change your character's attributes and abilities(respec) more than once in Diablo 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/can-you-reassign-or-change-your-characters-attributes-and-abilitiesrespec-mor)

One of the patches to Diablo 2 added a quest reward that allowed you to re-spec your characters skills. If a character had already completed all the quests prior to the patch, is there any way to get a respec for that character?

Edit: I'm aware of the technique mentioned in [Can you reassign or change your character's attributes and abilities(respec) more than once in Diablo 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/can-you-reassign-or-change-your-characters-attributes-and-abilitiesrespec-mor), but I'm not yet able to beat all the bosses in Hell.  Is there no free respecs for characters that existed before the patch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1.13 patchnotes says that all players who have completet the quests should receive 1 free respec in hell difficulty.

> Respecialization is now possible! Completing the 'Den of Evil' quest
>   will now additionally reward 1 free respec which can be saved.
>    **Players who have already completed this quest should receive 1 free respec in Hell difficulty.**

```
********************Keeping answer for original question**********************
```

Yes, as of patch 1.13 you can respec by collecting one of each essence and using them in the Horadiric Cube

> **1 of each of the Essences --> Reset of stats**
>
> In v1.13 a new choice was added. A character can now respec their
>   attributes. This is done by speaking to Akara after completing the Den
>   of Evil quest in Act 1.
>
> In that same version, after using all of the stat resets, if you're
>   still unhappy with your build, you can go out and defeat each of the
>   end bosses of each act in Hell difficulty to receive an Essence.
>
> They are just a bit more rare than keys are to complete the
>   pandemonium event.
>
> Only works in v1.13 or later

[source](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Horadric_Cube_Recipes#Respecs)

Comment: I was aware of this, I was wondering if there was a free respec given to existing characters or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to patch 1.13, everyone should have been given at least one free re-spec via Akasha on Hell difficulty. I believe you also could talk to her on the later difficulties for a free re-spec even if you had previously completed the Den of Evil quests on Normal and Nightmare.